# Construct a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \cup [4,5] \cup ...$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $\cup$ is finite, say $n$, I came up with formula

$f(x) = n x + i$, where $x \in [\frac{i}{n}, \frac{i+1}{n}]$, $n$ is non negative integer and $i$ differs between $0$ and $n-1$.

I'm not sure whether it's correct to assume the bijection holds if $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Assume $n=2.$ How do you define $f(1/2)?$ Note that $1/2\in [0,1/2]$ and $1/2\in[1/2,1].$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to know that a bijection *exists*, use the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem):

- The *identity function* is an injection from $[0,1]$ into $[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup\cdots$.
- $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$ is an injection from $[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup\cdots$ into $[0,1]$.

Since there are injections both ways, there is also a bijection.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

First of all define $f(1/n)=n-1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Thus we have covered the extremes of the union of intervals.

Now, define $f$ on $(1/(n+1),1/n)$ to be a bijection between $(1/(n+1),1/n)$ and $(2n-2,2n-1).$

Comment: A concrete construction. Nice! +1